# Java RPG game - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java

I am new at java programming and I was following a 2d rpg game tutorial and I've got stuck at one point. I don't know what causes this because I followed everything correctly, so I am asking for help why I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
at java.desktop/javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1400)
at tools.Loader.loadResource(Loader.java:11)
at tile.GrassTile.<init>(GrassTile.java:9)
at World.World.generateWorld(World.java:34)
at World.World.<init>(World.java:20)
at GameState.PlayState.init(PlayState.java:13)
at GameState.GameStateManager.init(GameStateManager.java:12)
at main.Main.init(Main.java:35)
at main.Main.main(Main.java:29)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at GameState.PlayState.render(PlayState.java:25)
at GameState.GameStateManager.render(GameStateManager.java:18)
at main.Main.paint(Main.java:62)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:907)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1083)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:907)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1083)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:590)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:907)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5262)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBufferedImpl(RepaintManager.java:1643)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1618)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1556)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1323)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1060)
at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(GraphicsCallback.java:39)
at java.desktop/sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(SunGraphicsCallback.java:78)
at java.desktop/sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(SunGraphicsCallback.java:115)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.paint(Container.java:2002)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.paint(Window.java:3940)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:876)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:848)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:848)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:823)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:772)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1890)
at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

My main:

```
  package main;

import GameState.GameStateManager;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Main extends JPanel {

    static Main game;
    Graphics2D g2d;
    static JFrame frame;

    public static int width = 640, height = 480;
    GameStateManager gsm;

    public Button button1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        frame = new JFrame("Jatek");
        game = new Main(); 
        frame.add(game); 
        frame.setSize(width, height); 
        frame.setVisible(true); 
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 

        game.init();
        game.run(); 
    }

    public void init() {
        gsm = new GameStateManager();
        gsm.init();
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                tick();
                repaint();
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void tick() {
        gsm.tick();
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2d.setColor(Color.gray);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

        gsm.render(g2d);
    }

    public static JFrame getFrame() {
        return frame;
    }

}
```

Loader:

```
package tools;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Objects;

public class Loader {
    public BufferedImage loadResource(String path, String fileType) {
        BufferedImage image = null;
        try{ image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(path + "." + fileType));
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return image;                  
    }
}
```

A tile:

```
package tile;

import tools.Loader;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class GrassTile extends Tile{
    public GrassTile(int x, int y){
        super(x,y,new Loader().loadResource("grass", "png"), false,TileType.GRASS);
    }
}
```

Worldgeneration:

```
package World;

import tile.Tile;
import tile.GrassTile;
import tile.DirtTile;

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class World {
    ArrayList<Tile> tiles = new ArrayList<Tile>();
    int worldWidth;
    int worldHeight;

    public World(int worldWidth, int worldHeight){
        this.worldWidth = worldWidth;
        this.worldHeight = worldHeight;

        generateWorld();
    }

    public void generateWorld() {
        Random r = new Random();
        int index = 0;

        for (int x = 0; x < worldWidth; x++){
            for (int y = 0; y < worldHeight; y++){
                index = r.nextInt(4);

                if (index == 0){
                    tiles.add(new DirtTile(x * Tile.size, y * Tile.size));
                } else{
                    tiles.add(new GrassTile(x * Tile.size, y * Tile.size));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public void tick(){
        for (Tile t : tiles){
            t.tick();
        }
    }
    public void render(Graphics2D g){
        for (Tile t : tiles){
            t.render(g);
        }
    }

}
```

The tile code:

```
package tile;

import tile.TileType;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class Tile {
    public static final int size = 32;

    public int x;
    public int y;

    public BufferedImage image;
    public boolean isSolid;

    public TileType tileType;

    public Tile(int x, int y, BufferedImage image, boolean isSolid, TileType tileType){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.image = image;
        this.isSolid = isSolid;
        this.tileType = tileType;
    }
    public void tick(){ }
    public void render(Graphics2D g){
        g.drawImage(image, x, y, size, size, null);
    }
}
```

If any other code is needed I will write it.

Comment: I forgot to say that it pops up as a white screen

Comment: Looks like this call `getClass().getResource(path + "." + fileType)` in Loader.java is returning null... Anyway, next time please don't dump *all* of your code on us and opt for a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead.

Comment: File `tools/grass.png` cannot be found on the classpath.

Comment: I am sorry for the long post. So it returns null but how do I make it return the image I need? Where should I put the resource folder?

Comment: You are certainly using IDE to code your codes. How to include the "resources" correctly is IDE dependent. A  blanket question about what folder cannot be satisfied by a generic answer.

Comment: See stacktrace - Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at GameState.PlayState.render(PlayState.java:25)- obviosly you have a problem in this class. But where is GameState and PlayState classes code?